# limit of floor function

Tags: functions, limits, fractions

I can solve the question limit of function like
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor x-3\rfloor}{x-1}
$$
but I cant solve the question like
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to n^\pm}\frac{\lfloor x-1\rfloor}{x-1}\\
\lim\limits_{x\to n^\pm}\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x-1}
$$
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that these are the questions your are asking and that $n$ is an integer.

As $x$ approaches $n$ from below, $\lfloor x-1\rfloor=n-2$; therefore,
$$
\lim_{\large x\to n^-}\frac{\lfloor x-1\rfloor}{x-1}=\frac{n-2}{n-1}
$$
As $x$ approaches $n$ from above, $\lfloor x-1\rfloor=n-1$; therefore,
$$
\lim_{\large x\to n^+}\frac{\lfloor x-1\rfloor}{x-1}=\frac{n-1}{n-1}
$$
With these as examples, try the others.